# Display checkbox from loop elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, simple-form

I have a form to create a new recipe. 
Each recipe can have multiple tags. 
I would like to display all the tags possibility and allow the user to check or uncheck them. 
I'm able to have a pretty display of the tags but I don't know how to turn them into checkboxes...
They have to be saved in the field `all_tags` as an array.

```
= simple_form_for @recipe, html: {multipart: true} do |f|
  - if @recipe.errors.any?
    #errors
      %p
        = @recipe.errors.count
        prohibited this recipe from being saved:
      %ul
        - @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          %li= message
  .row
    .panel-body
      = f.input :title, input_html: {class: 'form-control'}
      = f.input :description, placeholder: 'Dites nous ce que vous aimez dans cette recette ? où l\'avez-vous découverte ? avec quoi l\'accompagnée vous ? ...', input_html: {class: 'form-control'}
      = f.input :image, input_html: {class: 'form-control'}
      .tag-wrapper
        - @tags.each do |tag|
          %ul
            %li.tag.fa.fa-plus
              = tag.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
.tag-wrapper
  - @tags.each do |tag|
    = check_box_tag tag.name
```

EDIT:

If you need to save them as array try this solution:

```
= f.input :all_tags, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => @tags
```

Comment: Almost. I have all the checkbox but It do not display the name of the tags. And the field name is `all_tags`, where do I specified it ? I updated my post

Comment: Good, we are going forward :) The only thing is that instead of saving the array of all the `name`, it's save the array of all the `tag_id`... Here is how the HTML looks : 

          <label for="recipe_all_tags_8"><input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="8" name="recipe[all_tags][]" id="recipe_all_tags_8">Végétarien</label>

Comment: Try to use ```@tags.map{|tag| tag.name}``` instead of just ```@tags```

Comment: It works ! Thank you I lost few hours trying to solve this. Just a last question : Do you know why they are all display one over the over ? and not like a list or any other way which allow you to click on each.

Comment: You are welcome! You can update your question with some pictures and/or more info, because I don't exactly get your problem.

Comment: I'll post an other question about that because it moves away from the previous topic